# TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use this script for page pagination like in this tutorial http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/paginating-through-client-side-data.html

```
app.filter('offset', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = parseInt(start, 10);
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

Everything went fine, except that I got an error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
at k.<anonymous> (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/:18:17)
at e (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:171:180)
at db.| (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:160:65)
at F.constant (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:170:82)
at db.| (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:160:70)
at F.constant (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:170:82)
at Object.$watch.p (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:107:159)
at k.$digest (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:109:78)
at k.$apply (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:112:173)
at h (http://www.foo.com/43267ztX/default/js/angular.min.js:72:300) </pre>
```

Comment: So if `slice` isn't a property of `undefined`, which of your variables must be undefined? Your answer is in the error message.

Comment: show other codes... i got also error like that but the filter was not the reason.. try to review other codes you have.. but show other codes related to you filter will help..

Comment: Actually, that error is comprehensive. I am so sure that `input` is undefined.

Comment: I see no error. I use the jsfiddle on the site mentioned in the post. Can this be closed if it is not a problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
app.filter('offset', function(start) {
    return function(input) {
        start = parseInt(start, 10);
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

What does this mean?

1. Each filter must take an `input` and return an `output`.
2. Each filter must be built from criteria. This means, in the example: *given a certain start, give me a function which takes an input and produces an output slicing (start, 10)*.
3. It's much like the decorator pattern.
4. Don't believe me? Read the [official doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) to see how filters are high-order functions (functions that return functions - this functions become criteria factories, and the resulting function is used only on the purpose of the defined function).

What were your errors?

1. In the wrapper function (let's say), you must only give parameters which will have use on defining the function which will be the actual filter. You will use this filter as`{{ myArray|offset:3 }}`, and only receive ONE parameter: `(start)` which will, in this case, 3.
2. The wrapped function will take **exactly** one parameter (the name does not matter).

To illustrate this even more: (editing...)

Let's make a new filter, one with more caps than yours for one parameter:

```
app.filter('limit', function(start, count) {
    start = parseInt(start);
    count = parseInt(count);
    return function(input) {
        return input.slice(start, start + count);
    }
});
```

Each filter is kind of a *factory* (actually: it is a factory). This one takes two parameters and yields the actual filter. The actual filter is a function that takes a parameter and returns a filtered value. The inner criteria is defined by the parameters I passed to the wrapper function.

So when you use it like this:

```
{{ myArray | limit:5:5 }}
```

You say something like:

1. Take the arguments (5, 5).
2. Create a function which takes an input and slices it on (5, 10), and return it.
3. Apply that returned function to `myArray`.